# How to delete Multi-Device Hybrid Apps Preview/CTP2 manually?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

### Configuration

- Visual Studio 2013 SP3
- Windows 7 Pro SP1

### Problems

- *JavaScript Language Service* crashes and shuts down!
- *Cannot uninstall* **Multi-Device Hybrid Apps Extension**!!!!
- *Cannot locate* the vs2013mda_1.exe file?
- *Cannot reinstall* using vs2013mda_2.exe
- *Cannot work* with **LightSwitch HTML Client** projects
- *Cannot work* with **Bootstrap** Projects
- **Cannot uninstall, reinstall or repair extension**

---

I installed **Multi-Device Hybrid Apps Preview** (*VS2013mda_1.exe*) in August 2014 and after the install deleted the VS2013mda_1.exe from my downloads folder.

I discovered that after opening one of my LightSwitch HTML Client production applications, the **JavaScript Language Service crashes and shuts down**.

> Several people have reported similar issues where the JavaScript Language Service crashes and shutsdown for various project types -- LightSwitch, Bootstrap, etc... related to this extension..
>   **I Just want to delete/uninstall this extension**

When attempting to uninstall the **Multi-Device Hybrid Apps Extension** the program flashes by the progress screen and states **Setup completed successfully - The program was uninstalled.**

However, the extension is not removed from my workstation and still shows up as a project template type in Visual Studio 2013 SP3.

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913475/error-when-installing-visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova-ctp3-0-in-visual-st/26948928#26948928

Answer (score 7):

Please try running the following command (in Admin mode):

`"%ProgramData%\Package Cache\{dea88246-f74a-4171-ad6c-d9c978bf2973}\vs2013mda_0.1.exe" /uninstall /passive /force /burn.ignoredependencies={53d408db-eb91-43fb-9d8f-167681c19763};vsupdate_KB2829760`

Comment: I get an error: The extension with ID 'MultiDeviceHybridApps..db151788-9b27-49db-a5e2-d25a2653eb83' is not installed to any currently installed products

Answer (score 1):

I give error when run the manual uninstall command in power shell :D

run in the command prompt

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3014133