# Error when installing Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.0 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: compatibility, visual-studio-cordova

I installed Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio 2013 CTP 2.0.  I then updated VS2013 to update 4.  Now I can't upgrade MDHA to 3.0 because it tells me to uninstall 2.0 first, however the uninstaller doesn't work.  When trying to uninstall 2.0 from Programs and Features, it just goes through the setup and then doesn't remove the software from the Add/Remove list.

I tried following this however it doesn't work:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3014133

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up discovering that the package GUID in the the KB article is wrong.  I used this to uninstall the 2.0, then I could install 3.0.  The package ID may vary so you may need to search the directory for vs2013mda_0.1.exe and replace the command with your package location.

```
"%ProgramData%\Package Cache\{38f367f1-1468-4f16-a4c4-29747084003b}\vs2013mda_0.1.exe" /uninstall /passive /force /burn.ignoredependencies={53d408db-eb91-43fb-9d8f-167681c19763};vsupdate_KB2829760
```

Also,be prepared to wait.  This takes a long time.

Comment: As @netluke says in another response, the GUID inside the Package Cache folder is not fixed, so you better search for the EXE file and change the command line accordingly.  Besides that, I had to remove from the registry the keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies\{YOUR-GUID}\Dependents`.. after that my uninstall stopped doing nothing and finally removed the product!

Answer (score 5):

Thank you TechnoTim, the problem is that, every people has its own package GUID.

To solve the problem, you must lunch the command from the root directory, c:\, changing the package GUID with your package GUID.

In my system:

```
C:\>"%ProgramData%\Package Cache\{dea88246-f74a-4171-ad6c-d9c978bf2973}\vs2013md
a_0.1.exe" /uninstall /passive /force /burn.ignoredependencies={53d408db-eb91-43
fb-9d8f-167681c19763};vsupdate_KB2829760
```

To find the right package GUID I go to C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\ and search for
vs2013mda_0.1.exe and save the path in the block note, then change in path in the orignal command and lunch it from the root directory c:\, and its work.

Sorry fom my english.
Goodbye!

Answer (score 0):

"You cannot install Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.0 in Visual Studio 2013"

1. To resolve this issue, follow these steps to uninstall Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio CTP 2.0
2. Open a command prompt as an administrator.
3. Run the following command: "%ProgramData%\Package Cache{dea88246-f74a-4171-ad6c-d9c978bf2973}\vs2013mda_0.1.exe" /uninstall /passive /force /burn.ignoredependencies={53d408db-eb91-43fb-9d8f-167681c19763};vsupdate_KB2829760
4. Run vs2013mda_0.3.exe again for Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP 3.0.

The above worked when installing update 4, please see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3014133

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by another way.
I have tried to uninstall from command line, but no one of paths don't exists on my computer.
And I simply created another user with administrator permissions and installed new apache cordova tools from that user.
In my situation it correctly works running by new created user and old user.
Sorry for my horrible English.