# Unable to install Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to install CTP3 of Apache Cordova tools and have followed the instructions in the link.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3014133

But am still being blocked from installing. Here's the output from the log file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i001: Burn v3.7.3424.0, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: D:\Downloads\vs2013mda_0.3.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{2DD3EFE6-00FE-4C14-AABF-E3677FD848C7} {EE3A2D24-887E-4F17-9952-AA6E64863AD6} 5056'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing string variable 'EditionDisplayName' to value 'Tools for Apache Cordova for Visual Studio 2013 – CTP3'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing string variable 'UseCurrentCEIP' to value 'true'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'MoreLanguageFwlinkId' to value '427825'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'PrivacyAgreementFwlinkId' to value '427803'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'PrivacyStatementFwlinkId' to value '427803'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'MinOsLevelFwlinkId' to value '427813'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'SolutionFwlinkId' to value '427804'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'HelpFwlinkId' to value '427805'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'IE10FwlinkId' to value '427807'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'WinBlueFwlinkId' to value '427810'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'SHA256BlockFwlinkId' to value '427811'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Win81PreRelBlockFwlinkId' to value '427809'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing string variable 'NetfxProductVersion' to value '4.5.31111'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing string variable 'ProfessionalVSVersion' to value '11.0.50727'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:06]i000: Initializing string variable 'ProductKey' to value 'VVXKCDCCWD3B29PWQK2C3GYD7'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'D:\Temp\dd_mda_tools_20150213221707.log'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'D:\Downloads\vs2013mda_0.3.exe'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'D:\Downloads\'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Tools for Apache Cordova for Visual Studio 2013 – CTP3'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Ux Started
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Loading LocalizableStrings.xml string from LocalizableStrings.xml
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Current action: Install
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'CurrentOperation' to value 'Install'
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'IsLanguagePack' to value ''
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Current action: Install
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'CurrentOperation' to value 'Install'
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'CurrentRepairPackage' to value ''
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'HypervisorSupported' to value 1
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'HypervisorEnabled' to value 1
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Resume = None
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Restart = Prompt
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Relation = None
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Action = Install
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Display = Full
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'CustomInstallPath' to value 'C:\Program Files (x86)'
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'RelationType' to value 'None'
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'DisplayMode' to value 'Full'
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'NetworkAvailable' to value 1
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'OriginalDisplayMode' to value 'Full'
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'OriginalDisplayModeSwitch' to value ''
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  SetupAction: Install
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  ProductVersion: 12.0.31111.00
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  ProductLanguage: 1033
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Branch: VSUOOB
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  OS: Windows 8.1 Pro
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  OSVersion: 6.3.9600.0
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  OSLanguage: 1033
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  OSArchitecture: AMD64
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Ux Initialized
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Seen existing cache mutex '': False
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i100: Detect begin, 26 packages
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Wait for Detect to complete
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Detection Phase
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  ---------------
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'mdd_external_android_sdk_installed' to value 1
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Registry value not found. Key = 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment', Value = 'ANT_HOME'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'mdd_external_ant_system_installed' to value 0
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'mdd_external_ant_user_installed' to value 1
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'mdd_external_chrome_installed' to value 1
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe'; variable = 'mdd_external_chrome_user_installed'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'mdd_external_chrome_user_installed' to value 0
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'mdd_external_git_cli_installed' to value 1
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'mdd_external_itunes_installed' to value 1
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7'; variable = 'mdd_external_java_sdk_installed'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'mdd_external_java_sdk_installed' to value 0
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Node.js'; variable = 'mdd_external_nodejs_32_installed'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'mdd_external_nodejs_32_installed' to value 0
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'mdd_external_nodejs_64_installed' to value 1
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'MDDTools_DetectKey' to value 'Implicit (Multi-Device Apps)|$(VSInstallDir)\JavaScript\References\libhelp.js|$(VSInstallDir)\JavaScript\References\sitetypesWeb.js|$(VSInstallDir)\JavaScript\References\domWeb.js|$(VSInstallDir)\JavaScript\References\underscorefilter.js|$(VSInstallDir)\JavaScript\References\showPlainComments.js|$(VSInstallDir)\JavaScript\References\multiDeviceApps.js;'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'Powershell_DetectKey' to value '5.0.9883.0'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'ProfessionalVSUpdateVersion_DetectKey' to value '12.0.31101'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting string variable 'CurrentSqmOption' to value '0'
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i102: Detected related bundle: {53d408db-eb91-43fb-9d8f-167681c19763}, type: Dependent, scope: PerMachine, version: 12.0.31101.0, operation: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Detected related bundle. Installing bundle Lcid:1033  related bundle tag: vsupdate_KB2829760,1033
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Bundle Tag: PackageId=vsupdate_KB2829760, lcid=1033, IsLanguagePack=False
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Related BundlePackageId: vsupdate_KB2829760, Related Bundle Lcid: 1033
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Detected Related Bundle called with ProductCode: {53d408db-eb91-43fb-9d8f-167681c19763}
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'RelatedBundleTag_vsupdate_KB2829760' to value 1033
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Request adding Language Pack to list: Bundle Id={53d408db-eb91-43fb-9d8f-167681c19763}, Bundle Lcid=1033, Tag=vsupdate_KB2829760,1033, Action=Install
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Bundle Tag: PackageId=vsupdate_KB2829760, lcid=1033, IsLanguagePack=False
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i102: Detected related bundle: {86438e3d-7f83-4dd2-94aa-047e7c3974cb}, type: Dependent, scope: PerMachine, version: 12.0.30723.0, operation: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Detected related bundle. Installing bundle Lcid:1033  related bundle tag: vsupdate_KB2829760,1033
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Bundle Tag: PackageId=vsupdate_KB2829760, lcid=1033, IsLanguagePack=False
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Related BundlePackageId: vsupdate_KB2829760, Related Bundle Lcid: 1033
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Detected Related Bundle called with ProductCode: {86438e3d-7f83-4dd2-94aa-047e7c3974cb}
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'RelatedBundleTag_vsupdate_KB2829760' to value 1033
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Request adding Language Pack to list: Bundle Id={86438e3d-7f83-4dd2-94aa-047e7c3974cb}, Bundle Lcid=1033, Tag=vsupdate_KB2829760,1033, Action=Install
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Bundle Tag: PackageId=vsupdate_KB2829760, lcid=1033, IsLanguagePack=False
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i102: Detected related bundle: {9e6e5a9b-6f0e-40ff-84fb-19cab458402e}, type: Dependent, scope: PerMachine, version: 12.0.21005.1, operation: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Detected related bundle. Installing bundle Lcid:1033  related bundle tag: vs_ultimate,1033
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Bundle Tag: PackageId=vs_ultimate, lcid=1033, IsLanguagePack=False
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Related BundlePackageId: vs_ultimate, Related Bundle Lcid: 1033
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Detected Related Bundle called with ProductCode: {9e6e5a9b-6f0e-40ff-84fb-19cab458402e}
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'RelatedBundleTag_vs_ultimate' to value 1033
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Request adding Language Pack to list: Bundle Id={9e6e5a9b-6f0e-40ff-84fb-19cab458402e}, Bundle Lcid=1033, Tag=vs_ultimate,1033, Action=Install
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Bundle Tag: PackageId=vs_ultimate, lcid=1033, IsLanguagePack=False
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i106: Calculating patch applicability for target product code: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, context: Machine
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i106: Calculating patch applicability for target product code: {E9674444-9491-3961-873C-017D8912185E}, context: Machine
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i052: Condition '(NOT(RelationType = "Patch") AND NOT (CurrentOperation = "Install"))' evaluates to false.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: Preparation_Uninstall_mda_tools to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_chs ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_chs to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_cht ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_cht to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_csy ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_csy to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_deu ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_deu to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_enu ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_enu ProductCode: {E9674444-9491-3961-873C-017D8912185E} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_enu to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_esn ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_esn to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_fra ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_fra to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_ita ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_ita to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_jpn ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_jpn to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_kor ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_kor to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_plk ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_plk to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_ptb ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_ptb to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_rus ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_rus to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  DetectTargetMsiPackage called with BundleId: kb2963890_trk ProductCode: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA} Package State: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: kb2963890_trk to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: MultiDeviceHybridApps_VS.msi to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: mdd_external_java_sdk to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: mdd_external_android_sdk to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: mdd_external_ant to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: mdd_external_chrome to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: mdd_external_nodejs to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: mdd_external_sqlite to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: mdd_external_git_cli to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: mdd_external_websocket4net to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: mdd_external_itunes to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Adding package: Preparation_mda_tools to package detect list
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: Preparation_Uninstall_mda_tools, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_chs, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_chs target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_cht, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_cht target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_csy, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_csy target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_deu, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_deu target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_enu, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_enu target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_enu target: {E9674444-9491-3961-873C-017D8912185E}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_esn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_esn target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_fra, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_fra target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_ita, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_ita target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_jpn, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_jpn target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_kor, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_kor target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_plk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_plk target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_ptb, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_ptb target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_rus, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_rus target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: kb2963890_trk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i105: Detected package: kb2963890_trk target: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, state: Absent
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: MultiDeviceHybridApps_VS.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: mdd_external_java_sdk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: mdd_external_android_sdk, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: mdd_external_ant, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: mdd_external_chrome, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: mdd_external_nodejs, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: mdd_external_sqlite, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: mdd_external_git_cli, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: mdd_external_websocket4net, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: mdd_external_itunes, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i101: Detected package: Preparation_mda_tools, state: Absent, cached: None
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i000: Setting numeric variable 'RelatedBundleType_Dependent' to value 3
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:07]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i052: Condition 'NOT((VersionNT > v6.1) OR (VersionNT = v6.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1))' evaluates to false.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i052: Condition 'RebootPending = 1' evaluates to false.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i052: Condition 'RelatedBundleType_Addon > 0' evaluates to false.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i052: Condition 'RelatedBundleType_Patch > 0' evaluates to false.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i052: Condition '(MDDTools_DetectKey) AND (ProfessionalVSUpdateVersion_DetectKey >= v12.0.31101) AND (CurrentOperation = "Install")' evaluates to true.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i052: Condition '(MDDTools_DetectKey) AND (NOT (ProfessionalVSUpdateVersion_DetectKey >= v12.0.31101)) AND (CurrentOperation = "Install")' evaluates to false.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i052: Condition '(NOT (ProfessionalVSUpdateVersion_DetectKey >= v12.0.31101)) AND (CurrentOperation = "Install")' evaluates to false.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i052: Condition '(NOT (Powershell_DetectKey >= v3.0)) AND (CurrentOperation = "Install")' evaluates to false.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: VSU4andOlderMDDToolsBlock : You must manually uninstall the older version of Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova (Multi Device Hybrid Apps) by using the command prompt before continuing with this installation. For instructions, see !$!http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=518308&clcid=0x409,http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=518308!@!
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i000: MUX:  Wait for View to be loaded
[1484:0B50][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed, now create view
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i000: MUX:  View loaded
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i000: MUX:  Go to Blocker page.
[1484:1C14][2015-02-13T22:17:08]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I fixed the issue.

1. Searched the ProgramData directory for the vs2013mda_0.1.exe
2. Got the GUID name of the directory where vs2013mda_0.1.exe was located
3. Searched the registry for that GUID and deleted all instances
4. Ran the command "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{GUID GOES HERE}\vs2013mda_0.1.exe" /uninstall /passive /force /burn.ignoredependencies={53d408db-eb91-43fb-9d8f-167681c19763};vsupdate_KB2829760

The uninstaller then ran correctly.

Comment: About step 3: in particular I had to remove these keys to get it uninstalled: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies\{GUID GOES HERE}\Dependents`

Answer (score 1):

The answer in this earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913475/error-when-installing-visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova-ctp3-0-in-visual-st) suggests searching within the package cache directory on your system ("%ProgramData%\Package Cache") for vs2013mda_0.1.exe and replacing the command in the kb article with the package location found on your system. And when you execute the command, be sure to do so from whatever is the root directory on your system - e.g. c:\.